# Xcode how to parse Json Objects

Tags: xcode, json, uitableview, ios5

I manage to get Json for my server and parse in Xcode , I can then convert Json to a object and loaded my uitableview, the problems is my Json have 7 objects ..

you can see the [full Json here](http://pastebin.com/svyrDHtg)

```
2012-05-05 10:45:02.727 passingdata[63856:fb03] array : {
    posts =     {
        Friday =         (
                        {
                GymClass =                 {
                    "CLASS-TYPE2" = "";
                    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Intro/General";
                    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai";
                    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Friday;
                    TIME = "13:00 - 14:30";
                };
            }
        );
        Monday =         (
                        {
                GymClass =                 {
                    "CLASS-TYPE2" = "Fighters Training";
                    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Fighters/Advanced/Intermediate";
                    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai ";
                    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Monday;
                    TIME = "09:30 - 11:00";
                };
            }, ......
```

with this code I can get friday's "Friday" and display the GymClass info "GymClass" on my table

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData { //parse out the json data

    searchResults2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"array : %@",dictionary);
    NSArray *array = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"Friday"]; // retrieve that Day Gym Classes

    if (array == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Expected 'posts' array");
        return;
          }

    for (NSDictionary *resultDict in array) 
    {
        SearchResult *searchResult3;
        searchResult3 = [self parseTrack:resultDict];

        if (searchResult3 != nil) {
           [searchResults2 addObject:searchResult3];
        }        
    }    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (SearchResult *)parseTrack:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    SearchResult *searchResult1 = [[SearchResult alloc] init];

    searchResult1.classType= [[dictionary objectForKey:@"GymClass"] objectForKey:@"CLASS_TYPE"];
    searchResult1.classLevel= [[dictionary objectForKey:@"GymClass"] objectForKey:@"CLASS_LEVEL"];

    NSLog(@"parse track = %@", searchResult1);
    return searchResult1;
}
```

I can get the elements for one day but how do I get the Elements for every day (Mon,Tue...Sun)so i can display on my table by sections?

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well in your code, you already are doing that:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"array : %@",dictionary);
NSArray *array = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"Friday"]; // retrieve that Day Gym Classes
```

Wen can start from there to retrieve only the object `posts`:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *posts = [dictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

//Iterate over posts

for (NSArray *aDay in posts){
     //Do something 
     NSLog(@"Array: %@", aDay);
}
```

Here, i am using Fast Enumeration to iterate over the dictionary, you should check this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html).

Comment: Hi I know how to get info for one Day "Friday" , i am just don't know  how to get the info for all the days ..

Comment: @HernandoZ Take a look the second piece of code. There i'm not using `Friday`, only iterate over all

Comment: great thanks , so if I used Fast Enumeration what do i need to do ? save each day to NSArray ? then I would have 7 arrays to collect information from ? , sorry to be a pain can you explain what process I should follow to get all the days info in one table sorted by Day section, I know how to do it for one array which i did for "Friday" , but using multiple Array ? Thanks for your help ..

Comment: @HernandoZ You can use only the array `posts` as data source of a table view. The number of sections is the size of the array and the number of rows of each sections is the size of the n-array.

Comment: @ Jonathan Nuñez Aguin one more question , how do i divide the array posts in day sections? thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074594/json-parsing-in-ios-and-storing-the-results-into-array

Comment: guys can anyone tell how to display friday(any dictionary)->gym class->class level content alone.